# How does Ixalan drafting work with its double faced cards?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-double-faced-cards

Will Ixalan pack drafting change due to the double-faced cards? If the draft is sealed and not cube, people can see whether you have a double-faced card in your hand, if you are not careful.

Answer (score 10):

[This FAQ](http://wpn.wizards.com/en/document/magic-gathering-double-faced-cards-faq) has all the answers. Tl;dr: For the majority of tournaments, you **reveal all double-faced cards as they are opened**. And, since picks are put in a pile in front of you, **any opponent can see when you pick a double-faced card**. For further details (including e.g. what happens if you don't want to pick a card until you know if your opponent is choosing a double-faced card or not), see the FAQ.

There is also a way to draft completely normally using double-faced cards: tournament officials can open the packs beforehand and sleeve everything in opaque sleeves. However, while Wizards of the Coast does do this at some high-level tournaments, they suggest that your friendly local game store does *not* use this method so that the store and the judges can't get accused of stealing valuable cards from the packs they'd pre-open.